# Navigate to the Parent of a Parent of An Android Activity Using the Back Button

Tags: android, android-activity

My Activities are A, B, C. I have A start B, B start C. I need C to return to A using Back Navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set tag `android:parentActivityName` in your AndroidManifest.xml to achieve this.

Find Activity C's `<activity>` segment in AndroidManifest.xml and put this in there:

`android:parentActivityName=".package.app.ActivityA"`

Example:

```
<activity
        android:name=".package.app.ActivityC"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_c"
        android:parentActivityName=".package.app.ActivityA" />
```

Comment: This supports up navigation. Whereas I am trying to get back to Activity A using the built-in back button. The link was helpful. I need to clear the back stack. My code goes in public void onBackPressed().